# Bold format certain string in shiny datatable using regex

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables

I have a datatable in a ShinyApp. This datatable has a column with multiple strings. I need to format one string pattern in this column to bold using regex. The following reprex needs to bold string "H2", **but I need a regex solution**. I know next to nothing about javascript, so any help is very much appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data <- data.frame(V1 = 1:3, V2 = c("H1, H2, H3", "H5, H2, H6", "H4, H3, H5"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  "How can I make only 'H2' bold??",
  DTOutput("table", width = 500)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table <- renderDT(datatable(data))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: How is this question related to [tag:javascript]?

Comment: You can use native javascript code to modify anything in javascript based libraries, like `datatable` in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use e.g. `gsub` to wrap the text you want bold inside an HTML `b` tag and set `escape=FALSE` in `datatable()`.

**EDIT**: Following the suggestion from @DavidJorquera I generalized the code a bit by adding the serach pattern and the tag as variables.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data <- data.frame(V1 = 1:3, V2 = c("H1, H2, H3", "H5, H2, H6", "H4, H3, H5"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  "How can I make only 'H2' bold??",
  DTOutput("table", width = 500)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    pattern <- "H2"
    data$V2 <- gsub(pattern, paste0("<b>", pattern, "</b>"), data$V2)
    datatable(data, escape = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5145
```

[image]

Comment: This is not 100% what I expected but got me almost there and I finally could do what I wanted. `pattern <- "H2"` and `data$V2 <- gsub(pattern, paste0("<b>", pattern, "</b>"), data$V2)` did the trick for a more generalized solution. If you wouldn't mind I would appreciate if you could put that chunk on your answer.